# Get Position and Width of Parent Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to know how to get parent position and width with jQuery.
For example

```
<ul id="menu"><li>Parents</li>
    <ul><li>Child</li></ul>
</ul>
```

my jQuery:

```
if($('#menu > li > ul').children('li').hasClass('current-menu-item')){
//do animate
        left: $(this).parent().siblings().position().left;,
        width: $(this).parent().siblings().width();
    });
```

In case, I am at `<li>child</li>`. How to get position and width of `<li>parents</li>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parent = $('#menu .current-menu-item').parent().closest('li');
var position = parent.position();
var width = parent.width();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample HTML not match with your Jquery code. (**`current-menu-item` no element exist with this class**).

As you mention in question: You want to get position and width of the `<li>parents</li>`

So, you can use the [`> combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to select only immediate children.

```
var select =  $('#menu > li');
var left = parent.position().left;
var top = parent.position().top;
var width = parent.width();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut73j/2/)